# stream from Router HD to OSMC (both video and images)

Tags: image, raspberry-pi, kodi

I have a cbn cg7486g (wifi router) and it has a usb port where I can attach my usb HD and have it accessible for everybody in the (W)LAN.

I have my raspberry Pi (I) with OSMC in the living room connected via wifi, there I added the network drive as a source for both images and videos and I can see the files in there.

The problem is that my pictures are near to 3Mb each and just surfing through them is a pain. Is there a way to make it slideshow them with some pre-buffering or something that makes the experience nicer?

Sames question for videos. The playback facility is not that powerful and I cannot see the video without cuts every few seconds. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Can't find anything about that router, but I would think it's the USB not being fast enough?

Comment: I connected the HDD to the Desktop PC that have usb 3.0 interface (also supported by the HDD) but Kodi asks for credentials I don't have. I opened a question for the particular issue [**here a link to it**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34546061/acess-windows-shared-drive-from-raspberry-pi-osmc)